# Blazor WASM set Global class during program.cs for DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm fairly new to Blazor and I want to use a 'GlobalSettings' class. I have tried using CascadingParameters but I'm getting null errors in the console even though the site is displaying fine. I suspect due to the order of loading components.

So I'd like to use DI and have the class populated during program.cs so I can ensure it's available by the time the components start rendering.

After digging around in searches, I have setup a singleton in program.cs and all the while I explicitly set the values in the class, I can see them when the class in injected (Obviously). However, I want to get the values from an API. So I have setup a GetRequiredService - Which I can see runs the API call I need and fills out and instance of gs. When I breakpoint on `return gs;` I can see the value has been updated as required. However this is not persisted when I inject the class into MainLayout.razor.

I have a feeling I'm made a very simple error but got to a point where I can't see the wood for the trees! Any help, advice, pointers greatly appreciated. Code below:

program.cs

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new 
Uri(builder.Configuration["API_Prefix"] ?? builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TestInject>();
builder.Services.AddOptions();

var host = builder.Build();
var settingsService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<TestInject>();
await settingsService.GetStuff();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

TestInject Class:

```
public class TestInject
{
    public string TestItem { get; set; } = "Item A";

    public TestInject()
    {

    }

public async Task<TestInject> GetStuff() {

    var client = new ContentfulClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(), SiteConfig.CONTENTFULAPIKEY, SiteConfig.CONTENTFULPREVIEWAPIKEY, SiteConfig.CONTENTFULSPACEID);
    var queryBuilder = QueryBuilder<Globals>.New.ContentTypeIs("transitionConfig");
    var globalSettings = await client.GetEntries(queryBuilder);

    TestInject gs = new TestInject() { };
        foreach(var item in globalSettings)
        {
            gs.TestItem = item.phase1Title;
        }
    return gs; <-- Actually sets TestItem to the correct value
}

}
```

MainLayout:

```
@inject TestInject TestInject

@code {
    Console.WriteLine(TestInject.TestItem); <-- Still says Item A
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code illustrates how to write a service that can store and retrieve arbitrary objects.  You can register this with your builder, inject it in the usual way into your pages, and it will be always available.

**Interface:**

```
public interface IStorageService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified object to Storage, using the given key.
    /// </summary>
    void Add<T>(string key, T value);

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the object specified by the provided key from storage.
    /// </summary>
    void Remove(string key);

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the object corresponding to the given key.
    /// </summary>
    T Get<T>(string key);

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the object corresponding to the given key and removes it from Storage.
    /// </summary>
    T Pull<T>(string key);

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the given key exists.
    /// </summary>
    bool ContainsKey(string key);

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all objects from Storage.
    /// </summary>
    void Clear();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
/// <summary>
/// A container for state management.
/// </summary>
public class StorageService : IStorageService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, dynamic> _store = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified object to Storage, using the given key.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add<T>(string key, T obj)
    {
        if (_store.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _store[key] = obj;
            return;
        }
        _store.Add(key, obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the object specified by the provided key from storage.
    /// </summary>
    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        if (_store.ContainsKey(key))
            _store.Remove(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the object corresponding to the given key.
    /// </summary>
    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (_store.ContainsKey(key))
            return (T)_store[key];

        return default;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the object corresponding to the given key and removes it from Storage.
    /// </summary>
    public T Pull<T>(string key)
    {
        if (!_store.ContainsKey(key))
            return default;

        T result = (T)_store[key];
        _store.Remove(key);
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the given key exists.
    /// </summary>
    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _store.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all objects from Storage.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear()
    {
        _store.Clear();
    }
}
```

If you want it to be already populated with values, create a JSON file with your values and deserialize it in the Storage Service's constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This site is part of a larger project with project admins driving the content. We have the content sitting on a CMS and pulling it via an API. Part of this is that there are several items that we'd like admins to control that are site wide and this is the content that I'm trying to pull in and inject.  The idea is that project admins or content creators don't need any experience with editing JSON files etc in order to progress the project site.

Comment: The content for this service doesn't have to come from a JSON file; it can come from any data source.